# What files to be included under VSS 6.0

Tags: .net-3.5

For our .net 3.5 web project, what are the files which needs to be included under VSS 6.0? We have a distributed team of three vendors working on separate modules of our .net portal and all of them maintain their own setup and during release they send across the final build. No surprises that this has caused much headache and we have decided that we will keep this environment under our control and checkout the files when required. This is a multi-part questionnaire and to clear some basics first, we would like to know which are the important files to be kept under VSS6.0. 
Yes we know VSS 6.0 is outdated but we are playing a catchup game and till we move either to TFS or Subversion( atleast six months down the line) we need a VSS strategy.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Read [Team Development with Visual Studio .NET and Visual SourceSafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998239.aspx).